# tinymce upload NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Tags: firefox, upload, tinymce

I'm trying to add image uploads in a tinymce editor for a blog. I've tried a few things and the solution I found that I've got the furthest with is [here](https://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/direct-image-uploads-in-tinymce-4-42/).

With this soultion, on firefox (haven't tried other browsers but need firefox to work) I'm getting NS_ERROR_FAILURE in the console when I select a file to upload.

This is the code I have.
html with ejs (shouldn't affect the functionality)

```
<form class="form-group" method="post" action="<%= adminPage == 'New Post' ? '/admin/newPost' : '' %>">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
<input class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title" required>
<br>
<textarea name="content" id="editor" rows="20"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit post</button>
```

tinymce initialisation

```
<script src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({
        selector: '#editor',
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            $('#upload').click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, firefox wasn't allowing the form to post in a popup, I've changed the target to an iframe intead.